# More efficient collision detectors in Tiled 2d tilemap maker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile

To make a 2d tilemap for my simple 2d Unity game, I used the application Tiled. In doing so you are provided the option to give specific tiles collision detectors so you can make them execute code when imported back into Unity. I am using thousands of tiles with individual collision detectors that all do the same thing, and it feels awfully inefficient to have the CPU handle all of these simultaneously. Is there a way to connect all the tiles with collision detectors to each other as if to be one large collision detector? Or is there any way to make this process more efficient at all? Thank you.

Comment: What?! Why are you checking collisions on all of the tiles? You know the tile position, and the tile size, and you know where you are. In 3D quad or oct trees are used to do these kinds of checks efficiently.

Comment: @john I'm not using collision detectors on all the tiles, of course, but I do have a lot of tiles that need them.

Comment: Yeah, but my point is that you don't need to check collisions for every tile on every frame. If the tile is on the top left of the map, and the player is on the bottom right, there's no chance of a collision, surely?

Comment: @john I see your point, is this perhaps already done automatically or is there something I must manually do to make this happen?

Comment: I don't know enough about Unity to advise, I'm afraid.